# Get textfield input from another class

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I wanted to call an input from **mainGui.java** to **mainmenu.java** but it keep returns me NullPointException.

Below is my code for **mainGui.java**

```
String input;

public String user() {
        return input = logintext.getText();
}

private void submitbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        String input = logintext.getText();
            String input2 = loginpassword.getText();
             try {
                    lectFunc = (lectFunc)lectRecord.get(input);
                    if(lectFunc == null){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong username or password!");
                    } else if (lectFunc.getUser().equals(input) && lectFunc.getPass().equals(input2)){                       dispose();
                        new mainmenu().setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
                    }
                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
}
```

and code for **mainmenu.java**

```
public class mainmenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    lectFunc lectFunc;
    mainGui mainGui;

    public mainmenu() {
        final String user = mainGui.user();
        lectFunc.setUser(user);
        System.out.println(lectFunc.getUser());
        new mainGui().setVisible(false);
        initComponents();
    }
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

UPDATE: NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oodj.mainmenu.<init>(mainmenu.java:9)
    at oodj.mainGui.submitbtnActionPerformed(mainGui.java:158)
    at oodj.mainGui.access$000(mainGui.java:8)
    at oodj.mainGui$1.actionPerformed(mainGui.java:52)
```

Line 9 : `final String user = mainGui.user();`

Comment: NPE are very easy to fix. Please, reformat your code, then copy and paste the stack trace

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. Could you describe your problem more detailed? Where is an exception thrown? What does the stack trace look like? And, in your MainMenu, you never initialize `lectFunc`, so `lectFunc.setUser(user);` is bound to throw an exception.

Comment: Updated with NPE stacktrace

Comment: Ok, so mainGui is null. Maybe you don't initialize it, or maybe there's some code that set it to null

Comment: Is that because I can't call out value from private method?

Comment: `mainGui` is never initialised...

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the call to initComponents should be at the beginning. The main menu was probably not yet created.

Comment: I've tried call initComponents at beginning but still same problem.

Comment: Well there's a lot code missing. Perhaps you should provide more of it. From what you shared only guessing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign your newly created mainGui object to your class attribute:

```
public class mainmenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    lectFunc lectFunc;
    mainGui mainGui;

    public mainmenu() {
        ...
        mainGui = new mainGui();
        mainGui.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get exactly the same stack trace?

Comment: And did you do this *before* you called your `initComponents` method?

Comment: i did it both before and after still happening